# Intellisense does not work inside aggregates

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssms-17

When writing code in SSMS 17.6 I am noticing that IntelliSense does not work inside of aggregate functions. I always start with my table names so that way IntelliSense will suggest the column names for me which works fine. But when I for example have

```
select max(
from table
```

IntelliSense does not work inside the aggregate.
Is there a fix for this or is this just the way the system works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it, it works if you close the parenthesis of the aggregate and then type.